# How to use php logical operator with multi selection

Tags: php, logical-operators

How do you use the PHP logical operators with multi-selection?

Here is some [simple html dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) parse, I want to do some stuff, if the html content not include `div.title`, and not include `div.content`,  and not include `div.description`. (there were no three class type div, then process something).

But what I did like this, not work, still can do something include one type of div class. Need a help. Thanks.

```
if ($html->find("div[class=title]") == '' 
    && $html->find("div[class=content]") == '' 
    && $html->find("div[class=description]") == '') {
  // stuff working
}
```

**UPDATE**
well, I have solved it by myself. wrong with empty judge. close the question, thanks to all.

```
if ((!$html->find("div[class=title]")) 
  && (!$html->find("div[class=content]")) 
  && (!$html->find("div[class=description]"))) {
  // stuff working
}
```

Comment: What exactly does `$html->find()` return?

Comment: You can write an answer yourself and accept it. This might be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by myself. wrong with the empty judge processing.

```
if ((!$html->find("div[class=title]"))    
  && (!$html->find("div[class=content]"))    
  && (!$html->find("div[class=description]"))) {   
  // stuff working 
}
```

Comment: No need for the extra parentheses, `if (!$html->find(…) && !$html->find(…) …)` works fine.

Comment: yes, that's true. but i used to write some extra parentheses for see well.